# Remove Built-In Code Snippet from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-snippets

Is it possible to remove a built-in code snippet from VS 2012 so that it goes away forever and dies in a fire? The "remove" button is disabled in the Code Snippets Manager, but I was hoping maybe there'd be a resource file or registry entry or something that I'm missing.

The snippet in question: try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a snippet in Code Snippets Manager, the Location is listed in the text box above the list.  You can select that location, and paste it into an Explorer Address bar and open the file location of the snippet.  Just delete the offending snippet and you'll never see it again.